# How to to prevent Google from indexing

Tags: linux, htaccess, robots.txt

We have setup one of web site on server and site build in php and symfony framework, As my requirement is to prevent Google from indexing and below of my robot.txt and Is prevent using .htaccess?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

So How to to prevent it and test?

Comment: Last time I had to do something like this was after seeing them in my website stats. So if you don't see them in a while consider job done, maybe :|

Answer (score 4):

Your file should be named: `robots.txt`
If you can see the content of the file on line : http://youwebsite/robots.txt, then it should be working.
Otherwise you can test it with this google tool: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

Comment: Problem is that, get 404 file not found but file is exists, not works; How can I prevent Google from indexing in my project, I'm using 1and1.com panel, So Where to change it? -i'm confuses. pls just give a way...

Comment: What file shows a 404 error? The robot**s**.txt one? Be carefull about the 's' because in your first post you named it robot.txt

Comment: It's my bit mistake on htaccess file, So that not working but Now I have two   option for this 1) robots.txt and .htaccess ( http://www.htmlremix.com/seo/block-google-and-bots-using-htaccess-and-robots-txt )for prevent indexing ; So which one should better ?

Comment: The robots.txt solution is the best beaucoup every search engine will check it. Whereas in the .htaccess you will need to specify every search engine user agent. And if one is changing you will have to change the name in your .htaccess